# boost for android building boost log

Tags: android, c++, boost, boost-log

I am trying to build boost 1.54 for android. I am able to do it for date_time, filesystem, regex, program_options, signals, system and thread libraries of boost. But if I add boost log library among these, build fails as saying 'failed updating 8 targets'.

I appended following lines to my user-config.jam

```
import os ;

androidNDKRoot = C:/android-ndk-r8e ; # put the relevant path
 using gcc : android :
     $(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ :
     <compileflags>--sysroot=$(androidNDKRoot)/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
     <compileflags>-mthumb
     <compileflags>-Os
     <compileflags>-fno-strict-aliasing
     <compileflags>-O2
     <compileflags>-DNDEBUG
     <compileflags>-g
     <compileflags>-lstdc++
     <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include
     <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi/include
     <compileflags>-D__GLIBC__
     <compileflags>-D_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS
     <compileflags>-D__arm__
     <compileflags>-D_REENTRANT
     <archiver>$(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
     <ranlib>$(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
         ;
```

I also changed libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp file in order to compile threading libraries. You can find the necessary change [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8816#no1).

My build command is as following

```
set CXXFLAGS="-I%ANDROID_NDK%/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -I%ANDROID_NDK%/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include -I%ANDROID_NDK%/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi/include "
set TOOLSET=gcc-android

.\b2 --toolset=%TOOLSET% --user-config=./user-config-android.jam cxxflags=%CXXFLAGS% threadapi=pthread --prefix=..\boost_android_arm --builddir=./ target-os=linux --with-date_time --with-filesystem --with-regex --with-log define=BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3 --with-program_options --with-signals --with-system --with-thread link=static runtime-link=shared threading=multi install
```

As I already told before, it does compile if I don't type `--with-log` at build command.

Here are couple of lines from output,

```
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\gcc-android\release\build-no\link-static\log-api-unix\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\attribute_name.o
In file included from libs\log\src\attribute_name.cpp:32:0:
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:131:5: error: 'pthread_rwlock_t' does not name a type
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp: In constructor 'boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::light_rw_mutex()':
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:136:30: error: 'm_Mutex' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:136:43: error: 'pthread_rwlock_init' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp: In destructor 'boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::~light_rw_mutex()':
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:140:33: error: 'm_Mutex' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:140:40: error: 'pthread_rwlock_destroy' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp: In member function 'void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::lock_shared()':
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:144:32: error: 'm_Mutex' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:144:39: error: 'pthread_rwlock_rdlock' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp: In member function 'void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::unlock_shared()':
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:148:32: error: 'm_Mutex' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:148:39: error: 'pthread_rwlock_unlock' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp: In member function 'void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::lock()':
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:152:32: error: 'm_Mutex' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:152:39: error: 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp: In member function 'void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::unlock()':
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:156:32: error: 'm_Mutex' was not declared in this scope
./boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:156:39: error: 'pthread_rwlock_unlock' was not declared in this scope
```

It includes many lines like these, but these are the first error that it gave.

Can someone see what I did wrong or what should I change?

Thanks

Comment: As you already figured out, this type was not exposed until API 9 (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24228)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just changing platform to android-9 solved the problem.
After that it gaves another error which is already fixed in [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/85020)